# How can I get the type name from an instance in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var someType = function() {}
var instance = new someType();
```

How can I get "someType" from `instance`? `instance.constructor.name` or `instance.toString()` does not work.

**Update:**

I have no control of how someType is initialized. The type that I'm working with is declared in a third party framework.

Comment: why not just make `someType()` its own class? Then that would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because `someType` is the name of the *variable*, not the function/constructor.

You'd have to define the function as

```
var someType = function someType() {}
```

or

```
function someType() {}
```

> I have no control of how someType is initialized. The type that I'm working with is declared in a third party framework.

Then you are out of luck. If all you want to know is whether an object of a certain constructor function, you can use `instanceof`:

```
instance instanceof someType
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have control how someType is initialized because it's initialized in a third party control.

Comment: Updated my answer. There is not much else you can do though. You could try to contact the author of the library.

Comment: If I evaluate "instance" in a chrome dev. toolbar, it returns "someType {}". I can get the type name of an object in a chrome dev. toolbar but not in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named function expression

```
var someType = function someType () {}
var instance = new someType();

instance.constructor.name
>> someType
```